# realtime database - Firebase not updating

Tags: android, firebase

My Firebase database is not updating in android studio, it does not seem to be an error but here is what appears in the log:

any help would be appreciated

> D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=97 03-02 16:58:30.101
>   30441-30441/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat D/InputTransport:
>   Input channel destroyed: fd=94 03-02 16:59:07.175
>   30441-30494/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat D/TcpOptimizer:
>   [com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat] Full closed: sid=85,
>   tcpi_state=8

Comment: What are you using `addChildValueListener` or `addValueEventListener` ?

Comment: addValueEventListener

Comment: So simply in `addValueEventListener` there is method present known as `onCancelled`. Log `databaseError` here and check what exception is occuring.

Comment: mFirebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() - here is the code, I get an error on "addValueEventListnener"  cannot resolve method "addValueEventListnener" (anonymous.com.google.firebase.Database.ValueEventListner

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar kind of a problem. In my case I solved it by changing the database rules.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You already follow all steps in documentation?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0

You can also see the example here:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android

Comment: yes I have followed all the steps, my application works but the database is still not updating

Answer (score 0):

Change the Realtime Database Rules, The default values of read and write is 'false'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. the problem was with rules so I had to change it to

```
{
   "rules": {
       ".read": true,
       ".write": true
   }
}
```